# Google translate API V3: How to authenticate service account from file stream

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-translation-api

The default way for authenticating a service account for using the Google Translate V3 API is by means of an environment variable. This env var, called GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, points to a json file with the credentials, as described here:
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production

However, how can I use the required credentials when using a file in a different location? I am able to create the credentials object from a FileStream alright, as described in the google documentation. However, using this credentials object is only docmented for google cloud storage. The Builder for the TranslateTextRequest does not accept such a credentials object.
https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Cloud.Translate.V3/2.0.0/api/Google.Cloud.Translate.V3.TranslateTextRequest.html

The only workaround would be to copy the file to the location specified in the env var, but this seems odd and would fail when that variable isn't set.

Comment: Which language/SDK are you using? from the doc. link seems it is .NET but I am no sure.

Comment: Use **TranslationServiceClientBuilder** and specify **JsonCredentials** https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Cloud.Translate.V3/2.0.0/api/Google.Cloud.Translate.V3.TranslationServiceClientBuilder.html

Comment: @Iñigo Sorry, I should have specified that this is in Java.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks a lot. This looks like what I was looking for.

Comment: Does John Hanley suggestions solved your issue? Did you already try something? Did you get any error?

Comment: @martin_wun the environment variable is set where you run the request, so it doesn't matter where the file to translate is located ( generally it'll be in gcs). In addition [Cloud Translation docs](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/setup#auth), it suggests to use `service accounts for authentication and access control`.  What do you mean by different location and what exactly are you trying to do and where you want to execute that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, at last, I have been able to figure this problem out.

@JohnHanley Unfortunately, the class `TranslationServiceClientBuilder` was not available in my environment. Maybe it is DotNet specific. However, the hint was still very helpful, because I found another Builder which creates an instance of `TranslationServiceSettings`, which in turn has a static factory method, which in turn can be used to instantiate a `TranslationServiceClient`.

The following is the full solution for how to create a TranslationServiceClient from the file path to the Google JSON credentials file.

```java
TranslationServiceSettings settings = TranslationServiceSettings.newBuilder().setCredentialsProvider(new CredentialsProvider() {
    @Override
    public Credentials getCredentials() throws IOException {
        GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(credentialsFileAbsPath))
                .createScoped(Collections.singletonList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));

        return credentials;
    }
}).build();

TranslationServiceClient translationServiceClient = TranslationServiceClient.create(settings);
```

The anonymous class could also be replaced with a Lambda expression, of course.

@PjotrS Sorry about the confusion. The file I was referring to was the JSON credentials file, not the file to be translated.

Comment: Glad to hear you were able to solve it. Accept this answer to make it more visible that this solution works.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, Pjotr. Done and accepted. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a client using the static builder

```
TranslationServiceClient client = new TranslationServiceClientBuilder() { CredentialsPath = "C:\\path2urJSON\\ur-credencial.json" }.Build();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).